# Is there any web application to store passwords to a .db file?

Tags: apache-httpd, password, authentication, subversion

I am using Apache subversion to maintain repositories.

I am trying to implement it using a MAC book and unfortunately I could not use apache svn modules since it is giving me some run time errors.

I am using the svn protocol to implement the required.

I have some users whose details are stored in the passwd.db file in the configuration folder of repository which I am updating on regular basis to update the users.

However there is no confidentiality with respect to the user password since I myself changing it.

I am looking for a web application/module that could help me to create a dynamic password creation on user request or something like that provides complete confidentiality.

Regards

Shiv

Comment: Take a look at Subversion Edge: https://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

Comment: @Panki I am using mac machine and I couldn't find one for MAC systems in the link provided by you.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't catch that.